# Looking for Netplan example for generating OpenVSwitch vxlans

Tags: netplan

All:

Does anyone have a working example of defining an openvswitch vxlan in Netplan?

I'm unsure about where to define the ports (under ports? under bridges?) much less how to configure them using the openvswitch mapping.

Thx in advance,

-steve

Comment: the main netplan code repository has an openvswitch yaml example for netlpan, not sure if this will help or not but this is their examples in the code:  https://github.com/canonical/netplan/blob/main/examples/openvswitch.yaml

Comment: Please see `https://netplan.io` and `https://netplan.io/examples`.